# Is it ok to have a unit root within an independent variable?

Tags: multiple-regression, unit-root

The Dickey-Fuller and ADF tests testing for a unit root in variables are very sensitive.  Some econometricians have personally indicated to me that in some cases it may be acceptable to model a dependent variable that has a mild unit-root.  In other words, it does not trend forever in the same direction (pronounced unit root).  But, instead it does not quite mean-revert fast enough (mild unit root).

However, when it comes down to independent variables is unit root even a consideration at all?  Or, is it just as much as for a dependent variable with similar caveats?

Comment: If both the dependent and independent variables are I(1) and they share a common trend I would say yes. It is not really about variables having units roots, rather it is about whether the trends will cancel out so that estimators will have tight distributions.

Comment: Cagdas, is that in essence what a Cointegration model is?  Thus, within this framework the non-stationary trend of the dependent and at least one independent variable have to match closely.  If you have a mismatch, you have a problem.

Comment: If you care about a concrete problem (not just asking a theoretical question), why don't you update your post with the details. Then it might be possible to tell more exactly whether your approach makes sense.

Comment: Richard, we can make any hypothetical examples which would work just fine.  Let's say your have a model: GNP ~ S&P500 + Housing price + 10 Yr. Treasury rates.  If you take all those variables on a nominal level basis, they all have huge Unit roots.  Three of them trend upward forever (GNP, S&P500, Housing price).  You could detrend them all by looking at periodic % change (from one quarter to the next) and avoid the Unit root issue.  But, maybe you could keep them on a nominal basis (Cointegration framework).  I don't know.

Comment: Cagdas provided a practical note why this particular model could fail, but in principle you could use cointegration in similar situations. You just need the variables to be cointegrated, and that may or may not be obvious. I am not sure if a theory exists where GNP, stock market index, housing price index and treasury rates should be cointegrated (perhaps it does, but I have little experience with macroeconomic modelling). You would estimate a vector error correction model and then obtain its equivalent VAR representation for the levels of the original variables - to keep the nominal basis.

Comment: Cagdas and Richard, excellent comments.  Thanks much.  I have up-flagged them all.  Cagdas, I have no experience with Cointegration models; but, intuitively I so agree with you.  They seem to me like unicorns.  I can't see how two "level" variables could possibly have a difference between them that is stationary for long enough to build a model with.  Your State Space model is intriguing.  I'll have to study that.  Richard my econometric model example was just that, facilitate our conversation.  I am not suggesting there is any theory behind it suggesting they could be cointegrated.

Comment: Sympa, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260119/cointegration-relations-what-is-the-intuition/260131#260131) is the intuition for how cointegration occurs (to show it is not a unicorn phenomenon).

Comment: Richard, you are absolutely right.  It has been two years since I asked this question.  Since then, I have become very familiar with Cointegration and Cointegration models.  Thanks for your answer.