# Cointegration relations - What is the intuition?

Tags: self-study, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Cointegration relations - What is the intuition behind it? How can I find them?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? This is rather sparse.

Comment: I want to crasp the inuition of the concept - no idea where the problem lies with this questions. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find a constructive example easier than deductive ones, so here it is.

Suppose there is a unit-root process $x_t$. It could be the price of a company's share on a stock exchange, for example. Suppose you hold that share, and your friend holds another one. Let the price of your friend's holding be $y_t$ where obviously $y_t=x_t$.

Meanwhile, some other guy believes the company is going to fail, so he has short-sold two shares. (Simply put, short-selling is like holding the negative of them.) The price of his holding is denoted $z_t$ where $z_t:=-2x_t$, but you could also say that $z_t=-x_t-y_t$ or $z_t=-2y_t$.

Now if you all team up, the price of the total holding is $x_t+y_t+z_t=0$. You see that while each of the individual holdings was a unit-root process, the total holding is stationary (what can be more stationary than a constant). When that happens, we say there is cointegration: there exists a stationary combination of several unit-root processes. (This can be expanded to higher orders of integration etc., but the basic intuition does not change.)

Comment: Ok! I like the example! understood! Some how astonishing but cool!

Comment: Thanks, @Bonsaibubble! I did not get the intuition until I saw a constructive example in Davidson & MacKinnon ["Econometric Theory and Methods"](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/ETM/). Other textbooks often start from the other end and do not *construct* $y_t$ or $z_t$ but try to explain cointegration by saying "look, here are some random walks and -- boom -- their linear combination is stationary". So once I saw a constructive example in Davidson & MacKinnon's textbook, I loved it.